# Converting docker-compose to k8s manifest file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am working on a task to migrate all applications from docker container to kubernetes pods. I tried kompose but it's output is even further confusing.
Can someone please help me out here? I have run out of options to try.

Here is how my docker-compose file looks like:

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      auth_module:
        build: .
        extra_hosts:
          - "dockerhost:172.21.0.1"
        networks:
          - default
          - mongo
        ports:
          - 3000
    networks:
      mongo:
        external:
          name: mongo_bridge_network
```

Kompose output:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    items:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: Deployment
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe
            convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifest.yaml
          kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: auth-module
        name: auth-module
      spec:
        replicas: 1
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            io.kompose.service: auth-module
        strategy: {}
        template:
          metadata:
            annotations:
              kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe
                convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifest.yaml
              kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
            creationTimestamp: null
            labels:
              io.kompose.network/mongo_bridge_network: "true"
              io.kompose.service: auth-module
          spec:
            containers:
            - image: auth-module
              imagePullPolicy: ""
              name: auth-module
              resources: {}
            restartPolicy: Always
            serviceAccountName: ""
            volumes: null
      status: {}
    - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        name: mongo_bridge_network
      spec:
        ingress:
        - from:
          - podSelector:
              matchLabels:
                io.kompose.network/mongo_bridge_network: "true"
        podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            io.kompose.network/mongo_bridge_network: "true"
    kind: List
    metadata: {}
```

Comment: What sort of help are you seeking?

Comment: I am seeking help regarding how to mention this information such as extra-hosts, networks present in docker-compose in a k8s manifest file.

Comment: Those don't really translate to Kubernetes at all.  You might start by simplifying your Compose setup to not require `networks:`, `extra_hosts:`, or `build:`.  (If `dockerhost` is supposed to reach back to the host running the container, since Kubernetes is a multi-host setup, you might need some larger architectural changes since that won't be a single consistent host.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, that's poor form on the part of Kompose. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/ There IS a 1:1 construct mapped in the Kubernetes manifest spec. It should be directly translated. In my case, we have a Vagrant with a dedicated IP and resolve.conf entry that I need my local Minikube environment to talk to (legacy databases that I cannot spin up outside of that Vagrant, as well as using as POC for external resource sharing such as Kafka and Zookeeper in a hybrid environment). Kompose should address this shortcoming.